# Alternate text for custom counters in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have the following counters defined

```
static enum BadRecordCounters
{
    NO_CREATION_DATE, UNKNOWN_USER_ID, UNPARSEABLE_RECORD, UNTAGGED_POSTS
}
```

and they are displayed as below

```
14/05/06 21:43:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:   com.aravind.learning.hadoop.mapred.techtalks.StackoverflowDataWranglerMapper$BadRecordCounters
14/05/06 21:43:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:     UNKNOWN_USER_ID=93
14/05/06 21:43:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:     UNTAGGED_POSTS=2461
```

I am wondering if there is a mechanism to use alternate text for these. For e.g I want the counter group to be read as **Bad Record Counters** instead of FQCN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this function to increment your counters:

```
context.getCounter("PrettyGroupName", BadRecordCounters.NO_CREATION_DATE.name()).increment(1);
```

Comment: However when the counter is printed out as part of the job statistics it would still show as NO_CREATION_DATE right ?

Answer (score 3):

Map Reduce lets you modify the labels for counters specified in your programs via property files.

The Definitive guide has a section called "Readable counter names" which deals with this topic.

I am just reproducing the relevant section here

> The recipe to provide readable names is as follows. Create a
>   properties file named after the enum, using an underscore as a
>   separator for nested classes. The properties file should be in the
>   same directory as the top-level class containing the enum. The file is
>   named MaxTemperatureWithCounters_Temperature.properties for the
>   counters in Example 8-1.
>
> The properties file should contain a single property named
>   CounterGroupName, whose value is the display name for the whole group.
>   Then each field in the enum should have a corresponding property
>   defined for it, whose name is the name of the field suffixed with
>   .name and whose value is the display name for the counter.

```
MaxTemperatureWithCounters_Temperature.properties:
CounterGroupName=Air Temperature Records
MISSING.name=Missing
MALFORMED.name=Malformed
```

**The properties file should be in the same directory as the top-level class containing the enum.**